# regex in string is being stripped out when converting to BsonDocument

Tags: c#, regex, mongodb

I am creating quite a complex query for mongodb within .net using C#. To do this I am building the query as a string then parsing it to get a QueryDocument:

```
var Q = new QueryDocument(BsonDocument.Parse(QueryString))
```

My problem is that part of the query contains a regex:

```
{""Str.tagkw"":{$regex : "" \\b(rasberry|ice cream|sweeties)\\b ""}}
```

After parsing the $regex part has been removed when I look at the query Q (as above)

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to work for me:

```
string queryString = @"{""Str.tagkw"":{$regex : "" \\b(rasberry|ice cream|sweeties)\\b ""}}";
var Q = new QueryDocument(BsonDocument.Parse(queryString));
```

When you look at this in an IDE such as Visual Studio, it will be displayed as

```
{ "Str.tagkw" : / \b(rasberry|ice cream|sweeties)\b / }
```

That's the Javascript representation: In Javascript, you can create regular expressions using either

```
var regex = new RegExp("(foo|bar)");
```

or, as syntactic sugar

```
var regex = /(foo|bar)/;
```

The `ToString` method which will be used by the debugger seems to prefer the second representation, but that's just a matter of how it's displayed.

Comment: Thanks for that, I may be missing something here, but when I use the mongodb command line I can return results using

` {"Str.tagkw":{$regex : " \\b(rasberry|ice cream|sweeties)\\b "}}`

but it does not return results using:

`{ "Str.tagkw" : / \b(rasberry|ice cream|sweeties)\b / }`

Comment: Ok - had a play with it and removed space between the / \b......\b / and it worked! Thanks!